# How to catch FileNotFoundException from MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

I am using a `MediaPlayer` that grabs videos from URLs:

```
 try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I try and set a datasource with a url, that for instance, has been taken down, I get the following error in my logcat:

> Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   http://example.com/examplevideo.mp4

However, my `catch{}` does not trap this in the following code above, which I need it to do so I can display an error message etc...

Is there any way to catch this FileNotFoundException in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can catch that error with ```MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for replies.

I forgot to mention that the file is from an external server, but have adopted an approach similar to what Pramod suggested, but altered to suit my needs.

```
 /**
     * Checks if an external file on a server exists.
     * @param urlString The file URL
     * @return true if file exists, false if does not
     */
    public boolean checkExternalFileExists(String urlString){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            int response = ((HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()).getResponseCode();
            return response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to catch this specific exception. But you can use following to catch any type of exception.

```
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.i("your tag",e.toString());
    }

and look at the log with the tag you whant
```